# Retrieving the span of a fuzzy match

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to fuzzy-search for a short text in a larger text.

Common python libs, such as fuzzywuzzy and rapidfuzz, support the "partial_ratio" function, but those only return a score, not the location of the match.

Is there some library or function which I can use to also obtain *where* the fuzzy match was, (something like the span method of regex match)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) and noted that finding the [index of a match is an open issue](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/issues/293). The same is true for [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz/issues/41).

This prompted me "(something like the span method of regex match)" to do some research around this method.  During my research I found the Python package [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).  The package's Readme talks about [fuzzy matching](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#approximate-fuzzy-matching-hg-issue-12-hg-issue-41-hg-issue-109). I haven't used this package, but it seem that it might be useful to solving your use case.